# ruby - use take_while with map iterator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble with something seemingly basic. Essentially I want to do something like this:

```
result = reports.map do |rep|
  rep.calculate_distance
  break if rep.msg_code == 5
end
```

But rather than returning something like this:

```
 => [#<BigDecimal:7fc7036c63b8,'0.3962736920 816792E7',18(45)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc7066061c8,'0.1603401548 194003E4',27(45)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc70601fb60,'0.1707572852 613187E3',27(45)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc706176220,'0.4645528504 455211E3',27(45)>, #<BigDecimal:7fc70667e448,'0.1058402703 80584E4',27(45)>]
```

It returns this:

```
 => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

So then I try this:

```
reports.take_while {|rep| rep.msg_code == 5 }.map(&:calculate_distance)
```

But it gives me this:

```
 => []
```

And I know for fact that none of the msg codes are equal to 5, so it should be returning the big decimals in an array, but it doesn't.

So how do I get take_while to work with map in order to get the desired results?

Comment: You need to provide more information on your problem to be solved here.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu The problem is that I want to return an array of big decimals. calculate_distance is a method of a rails object that returns big decimals. I want to continue doing it until the msg_code method of the rails object is equal to 5. The rails object contains both a calculate_distance and msg_code method. The result should be na array of big decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to continue doing it until the msg_code method of the rails object is equal to 5

```
reports.take_while{ |rep| rep.msg_code != 5 }.map(&:calculate_distance)
```

Basically `!= 5` instead of `== 5` in your `take_while` predicate.

Comment: @JohnMerlino no rush, you may get a better answer ;)

Comment: That's the way to go. Just comment that, the same way we have select/reject, so can implement the complementary `take_until` to keep positive logic in the block.